# Boundary conditions and CPT theorem on lattice

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lattice-gauge-theory

Take scalar fields for simplicity. How can one guarantee that the fields obeying the boundary conditions have the correct symmetries from the perspective of CPT theorem? A little bit of details will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/664759/2451

Comment: Hi Iosuf. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.